# asp.net web forms project url routing not working for one page

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web forms project and normally when I add a new page the routing picks it up automatically but its not working for one page only, I have added it, deleted it and added it again but it keeps trying to hit a directory named Forum not the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, there was a directory named the same as the page so it was trying to hit that instead... :(